# Animated Collapsibles

Tags: javascript, html, css

I found this nice future to collapse elements on w3schools: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_collapsible_symbol

I would like to revert it, so that all elements are shown when page is loaded, and then use this future to toggle between visible/hidden..

I have this code:

```
<style>
.collapsible {
  background-color: #777;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  
}

.collapsible:after {
  content: '\002B';
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.collapsible.active:after {
  content: "\2212";
}

.content {
  padding: 0 20px;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
</style>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
        var i;

        for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
          coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
            this.classList.toggle("active");
            var content = this.nextElementSibling;
            if (content.style.maxHeight){
              content.style.maxHeight = null; 
            } else {
              content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
            } 
          });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Example here:  https://jsfiddle.net/g50v4cL2/

So when page is loaded, i want to have it like this:

[image]

And then able to collapse.. can anyone help me with this?

Thank you.

Comment: Your drop-down blocks must be open by default, which means that these blocks must have a **height**! Why do you need an extra piece of javascript code? Moreover, it is a crutch. I do not impose my opinion, but you better use my correct solution. Since further, you may get confused, and problems in coding will arise.

Comment: Your solution works with static height of an <div>.. but in my project i dynamically add checkboxes to the <div> element, so in the start i don't know the exact height..I used @Zac solution because its working with dynamic height of a div (which can containt N elements of checkboxes..)..Anyway, i appreciate your help! :)

Comment: If you could show you how you add checkboxes dynamically... You know better what you need anyway :)

Comment: @s.kuznetsov It is a little bit complicated to show you here, because checboxes are dynamically added based on other stuff in my project..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're many ways to do it, in this case, I tried to not make many changes and to stick to the way you have, so you can just add `active` class to your elements, and change your js code a bit to be like this:

```js
        var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
        var i;

        const adjustContentHeight = (content) => {
          if (content.style.maxHeight){
              content.style.maxHeight = null; 
          } else {
              content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
          }
        }

        for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
          adjustContentHeight(coll[i].nextElementSibling);
    
          coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
            this.classList.toggle("active");
            adjustContentHeight(this.nextElementSibling);
          }); 
        }
```

```css
.collapsible {
  background-color: #777;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  
  
  
}


.collapsible:after {
  content: '\002B';
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.collapsible.active:after {
  content: "\2212";
}

.content {
  padding: 0 20px;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<button class='collapsible active'>Test1</button>
<div class='content'>
<label><input type = 'checkbox' value = 'value1'/> value1</label>
<label><input type = 'checkbox' value = 'value2'/> value2</label>
<label><input type = 'checkbox' value = 'value3'/> value3</label>
<label><input type = 'checkbox' value = 'value4'/> value4</label>
</div>



<button class='collapsible active'>Test2</button>
<div class='content'>
<label><input type = 'checkbox'  value = 'value5'/> value5</label>
<label><input type = 'checkbox'  value = 'value6'/> value6</label>
<label><input type = 'checkbox'  value = 'value7'/> value7</label>
</div>
```

If you don't want to see this transition in the beginning, consider removing the transition property from css and adding it in js after this code